# CSS not loading instantly in webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack

Here is the image which shows the first time of loading

[image]

After microseconds, everything is fine such as design, javascript, images, etc...

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',

    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        // Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: function () {
                                return [
                                    require('autoprefixer')
                                ];
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        // Loads a SASS/SCSS file and compiles it to CSS
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            },

        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

I don't know what I'm missing but I know definitely missing something but not indicating. I tried but didn't get it to work.

I'd really appricitate if could help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently CSS always loads after JS. Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/issues/269).

You could also set `display: none` to your `body` or main `div` and change it in the CSS. It would take the same time to load, but you wouldn't see ugly styled content during those microseconds.

Comment: Wow, this actually works. Just make sure that you don't do this in the tag's `style` attribute, but in a `<style>` tag. CSS always gives the attribute higher priority, so if you do it there, nothing will display at all.